# Is it possible to give a dialog for choosing which user to sign in with Facebook?

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

So, when a user clicks my Sign In button, it signs in successfully. However, what if I want my users to be able to change their facebook account? Facebook doesn't give us a single hint on this. Even clearing app cache doesn't work. Google works fine, but facebook doesn't. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The user is only allowed to have one Facebook account. So they should need to switch

Comment: @WizKid In my case, I had an account on gmail (x@gmail.com), and the facebook account is registered with that email. I signed into my app with Google with that email, then I logged out and I tried signing into facebook. It didn't let me since I already have an account with that email. Now I want to change it, but, it's not working.

Comment: In the end I just allowed multiple email addresses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't give an option for this. There's no way for doing this.